# Advantages of XML DataType in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, xml-serialization

I was trying to understand the basic advantage of using <kbd>XML</kbd> DataType in SQL Server 2005. I underwent the article **[here](http://weblogs.asp.net/eporter/archive/2005/11/27/431649.aspx)**, saying that in case you want to delete multiple records. Serialize the XMl, send it in Database and using below query you can delete it..

[image]

I was curious to look into any other advantage of using this DataType...

**EDIT**

**[Reasons for Storing XML Data in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345115%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)**

Here are some reasons for using native XML features in SQL Server 2005 as opposed to managing your XML data in the file system:

1. You want to use administrative functionality of the database server for managing your XML data (for example, backup, recovery and replication).

   **My Understanding** - Can you share some knowledge over it to make it clear?
2. You want to share, query, and modify your XML data in an efficient and transacted way. Fine-grained data access is important to your application. For example, you may want to insert a new section without replacing your whole document.

   **My Understanding** - XML is in specific column row, In order to add new section in this row's cell, Update is required, so whole document will be updated. Right?
3. You want the server to guarantee well-formed data, and optionally validate your data according to XML schemas.

   **My Understanding** - Can you share some knowledge over it to make it clear?
4. You want indexing of XML data for efficient query processing and good scalability, and the use a first-rate query optimizer.

   **My Understanding** - Same can be done by adding individual columns. Then why XML column?

Comment: The basic advantage is .... that it's `XML` ! With all its benefits. And you can query it "in place" to extract values from it. And it stores the data in an optimized compact format.....

Comment: Thanks a lot for your presence. Will it create some Performance issue comparing it with creating columns ? and can you explain your reply in more details pls? thanks in advance

Comment: The XML is stored in a compact, tokenized fashion - using 20-40% less space than when stored as a textual column

Comment: @marc_s - Can you share the link for this sentence **"stored in a compact, tokenized fashion - using 20-40% less space than when stored as a textual column"**

Comment: We using it a lot, when you need to pass array of values, or rows into stored procedure from client side.

Comment: If you look at [XML Support in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) or lots of other links, you'll often see *stored in an optimized fashion* or something like that. The 20-40% is my own observation - store a few thousands rows of XML data (file size from 1K to 50K each), both as `XML` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)` - and that's the storage difference you will see.

Comment: @marc_s, just to summarize my understanding that `XML` `DataType` should be the case when you have lee number of records right? Last question, in which scenario I will have to use this DataType?

Comment: Read [XML Best Practices in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345115%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and follow their advice. Don't over-use XML - don't start storing XML data inside SQL Server unless you **have to** (because you get it as such, from a source, or because you need to send it somewhere in this format). Don't use XML to "replace" relational tables.

Comment: @marc_s - I studied from the reference as you mentioned in your comment. I have some doubts in my query and edited it in my original query after studying you suggested article. Can you spare from you very important time to look into it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pros:
Allows storage of xml data that can be automatically controlled by an xml schema - thereby guaranteeing a certain level of data quality
Many web/desktop apps store data in xml form, these can then be easily stored and queried in the database - so it is a great place to store xml data that an app may need to use (e.g. for configuration settings)

Cons:
Be careful about using xml fields, they may start off as innocent storage but can become a performance nightmare if you want to search, analyse and report on many records.

Also, if xml fields will be added to, changed or deleted this can be slow and leads to complex t-sql.

In replication, the whole xml gets updated even if only one node changes - therefore you could have many more conflicts that cannot easily be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I would say of the 4 advantages you've listed, these two are critical:

> You want to share, query, and modify your XML data in an efficient and transacted way

SQL Server stores the XML in an optimised way that it wouldn't for plain strings, and lets you query the XML in an efficient way, rather than requiring you to bring the entire XML document back to the client. Think how inefficient it is if you want to query 10,000 XML columns, each containing 1k of data. For a small XPath query you would need to return 10k of data across the wire, for each client, each time.

> You want indexing of XML data for efficient query processing and good scalability, and the use a first-rate query optimizer

This ties into what I said above, it's far more efficiently stored than a plain text column which would also run into page fragmentation issues.

Comment: can you explain the advantage of using XML DataType and in which scenario it can be benificial?

Comment: @Nilish when you want to store XML, it's that simple :)